# Working with Gravatars within a localhost development area

Tags: author, gravatar

Is is possible to add an author photo (gravatar), while developing our WordPress site offline in a /localhost environment?  I see that the gravator process is requesting for an online site to be associated to, but my site is still in a development stage offline.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make gravatars work offline (they completely rely on remote service), but you can get rid of erorrs and slowdown when offline by overriding them. You can use `get_avatar` filter for it.

There is an Airplane Mode plugin for offline WP dev that does this (among other things). You can use that or just [check out its implementation](https://github.com/norcross/airplane-mode/blob/0a4cac30ddfddf4d859886e82b07411230106a29/airplane-mode.php#L441-L454).

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on the topic and I will check out the resource as well.

Comment: I just checked out the plugin.  This was such a clever idea. Thanks again for bringing it up!